# Bash convert text HHMMSS to HH:MM:SS

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am reading a csv log file where the time stamp (1st column) is in the format of HHMMSS where HH is the hour (0-23), MM is the minute (0-59), SS is the seconds (0-59).

I already read the file and do various conversions on column data so the time stamp is in a variable lets say CURRTYME. I currently convert as follows

```
# Data will have leading zeros and will always be 6 characters
CURRTYME="073031"
NEXTTYME=`echo $CURRTYME | sed 's/./&:/2'`
LASTTYME=`echo $NEXTTYME| sed 's/./&:/5'`
echo $LASTTYME
```

Is this the best way to accomplish the insertion or can I do it in one sed statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

CURTIME="073031"

echo $CURTIME | sed "s|\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)|\1:\2:\3|"
echo $CURTIME | cut -c-2,3-4,5- --output-delimiter=:

echo ${CURTIME:0:2}:${CURTIME:2:2}:${CURTIME:4:2}
```

The last one requires `bash`.

Or you can go to `awk`, but for such small task it would be overkill

Comment: So this is 3 ways to achieve the same desired result right?  Is any of them more efficient?  (Maybe the last?)

Comment: Yes, as long as you are using `bash`, the last one is the fastest, since it does not require external processes. But for general task 'read and convert CSV' it is better to use `Perl` or `awk` instead of pure shell.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a CSV file with headers like this:

```
time,data A,data B
123456,abba,baab
654321,quux,uxqu
```

... the first field, `time`, can be converted from `NNNNNN` into `NN:NN:NN` using Miller (`mlr`) like so:

```bash
$ mlr --csv put -S '$time = sub($time,"(..)(..)(..)","\1:\2:\3")' file
time,data A,data B
12:34:56,abba,baab
65:43:21,quux,uxqu
```

This reads the data as CSV and uses a substitution command (`sub()`) to convert the named field `time` into the wanted format for each record in the file.

The substitution matches the six first characters in the `time` field in three groups of two characters each and inserts colons between the groups.  The `-S` option for the `put` sub-command avoids inferring the field type, allowing us to treat it as a string rather than a number.

If given the option `-I`, `mlr` will edit the file "in-place".